# Accessing a Folder on Linux from web application deployed on different server

Tags: java, linux, web-applications, mount-point

I have a web application deployed on  server let's say 'A'. On this server, We have created a mount point for /usr/local/B directory of Linux file system.  Will I be able to check the content of this directory B from Java based web application deployed on server A? If yes then how?

Comment: Do this in the operating system and just let Java see files

Answer (score 0):

Mount point serves the very same way as physical drive and is transparent to applications. So yes, you will

Making mount points under /usr/local is generally bad idea. You have /mount partition for that

Comment: Inside B directory I have another directory C, and I am trying to check if this directory exists or not with code: File f = new File("/C"); if(f.exists()){sysout("directory exists")}. Will this work or do I need to change the path in File object.